# Trying to sum a count distinct in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, case, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to find a count of distinct Id's when a code = "MD".  The table below would give me a count of 2.

```
    LastName  FirstName  PracId  Code
    Jones     Tom        100     MD
    Jones     Tom        100     MD
    Smith     Robert     200     DO
    Azir      Azul       300     MD
    Azir      Azul       300     MD
```

I've been playing around with something like this:

```
    Select lastname, firstname, sum(count(distinct pracid) where code = 'MD')) from test group by lastname, firstname
```

I'm getting the "cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate" error.  I did this before several years ago using a Case statement, but I can't recall how that worked.

Does anyone know how to do this calculation?

Comment: what do you need the `sum` for?, the count distinct seems enough

Comment: Count distinct just gives 1, 1, 1, for each matching record.  I need 3.

Comment: but you are still grouping by the names...you'll need to post the desired result

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the count aggregate function as follows:

```
SELECT lastname, firstname,COUNT(DISTINCT PracId) as Cnt_PracId
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE Code='MD' 
GROUP BY lastname, firstname
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following query:

```
SELECT lastname, firstname, count(distinct pracid) 
FROM test
WHERE code = 'MD'  
GROUP BY lastname, firstname;
```

Comment: This will just give 1, 1,1, etc. next to each record. I need something like: Jones Tom 100 MD 3

Answer (score 0):

```
  ;with cte( LastName,  FirstName,  PracId,  Code)
  As
  (
 SELECT  'Jones' ,    'Tom'   ,     100,   'MD' Union all
 SELECT  'Jones' ,    'Tom'  ,     100,   'MD' Union all
 SELECT  'Smith' ,    'Robert',     200,   'DO' Union all
 SELECT  'Azir'  ,    'Azul'  ,     300,   'MD' Union all
 SELECT  'Azir'  ,    'Azul'  ,     300,   'MD' 
 )
 SELECT LastName,  FirstName,  PracId,  Code,COUNT(1)over() as DistinctIdCount  From
 (
 SELECT * ,Row_number()Over(Partition by PracId,Code order by Code )seq FROM cte
 )dt
 where dt.seq =1 and DT.Code='MD'
```

Comment: I can't do a UNION ALL on every record.  There is a way to do it using the Case statement, but I just can't recall the way.

Comment: you can pull data from you table i have pulled the data from cte for an instance,that doesn't means you have to do union all